# Create a table with student ID starting with a letter - mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, composite-key

I need to create a table for students with ID's starting either M or I and then followed by 7 digits. I thought about creating a table one field being choosing the letter M or I and the second field be the 7 digits. Then I would use those to create a composite primary key. But I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I would like one column for the student ID.

This is what I have so far:

```
   create table student(    
       student_id_first ENUM('M', 'I')  
       , student_id_digits  char(8) not null    unique  
       , first_name varchar(50)
       , last_name   varchar(50)    
       , Primary Key(student_id_first, student_id_digits)   
    )   ;
```

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: why not do it in your application level? database is used as a storage of data.

Comment: Is the reason the ID has an M or I in it for legacy code reasons?  If not, may I ask why you want to do that?  If it's to indicate something about the student, I personally wouldn't use the primary key in that way to do it.

Comment: @Marvo, I'm doing this for homework. And this was assigned.

Comment: I would suggest googling  "mysql check constraints".

Answer (score 1):

You should not be putting data validation in your database layer. You're also creating a compound key which adds additional, unnecessary overhead. If at some point you need to adjust or relax the rules, you need to re-define the database schema.

This also introduces pointless complexity when retrieving data and having to assemble the actual student identifier. Unless you have a very good reason for splitting them, keep them together.

Just use one column and enforce what goes in there in your application. Even a very basic ORM will give you the ability to do this.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But I can't relax the rules if it's for homework. :/

Comment: The only real constraints you can enforce in MySQL are data type, if `NULL` is allowed, or the length of the value. Since `CHECK` constraints aren't supported, you could be using the wrong RDBMS for this assignment unless there's some (presumably shudder-worthy) way to do this using `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest approach here is to define a field `id char(8)` and make it the primary key.

The question that opens up (the question your teacher may ask) is "what happens if some rogue software client inserts an id like 'K1234567', 'DEADBEEF', or 'I123' that doesn't comply with your business rule for id values?"

Potentially valid answers to this question for you to give to your teacher are:

1. if we were in production we would test the software clients to prevent this happening.
2. we can run a daily production purge process to get rid of rows with malformed id numbers.
3. what the heck do you want? this is a week's homework for a two credit hour class! I already gave you a schema that's just as good as most payroll systems!

Seriously, it does not sound from your original question that your teacher is insisting that you design a dbms schema that enforces this particular business rule.  But only you know if that is the case.

Comment: Ha! I gave her the response, "Why do we need that letter?" And she said, "because I said so."

Comment: Fair enough. It often makes no sense to argue with requirements. If you were creating software for a university library, and you said "Library of Congress (LOC) catalog numbers are too hard; let's switch the library over to the Dewey Decimal System," the library director would laugh and then fire you.  So, you have to implement the specified number system (with a letter).  The question is whether you can simply store each ID value in a text string, or whether you MUST use character and an integer. I say, use a text string! It's easier! It would be for LOC catalog numbers too.